# Why is the value saved in a table different from the one used in the INSERT query?

Tags: mysql

When inserting a date, the value stored in the database is different from the value inserted

For example, when executing the following query, I hope that the values in the `startdatetime` and `enddatetime` columns are both equal to `2020-02-02 00:00:00` but in the table the values are `2020-02-01 23:00:00`

```
INSERT
INTO
    tasks
(hours, startdatetime, enddatetime, description)
VALUES
(0.03, '2020-02-02 00:00:00', '2020-02-02 00:00:00', 'demo');
```

I understand that this behavior is related to Time Zone, because when executing the same query from console and first set the timezone the saved value is correct

```
SET time_zone = '+00:00';

INSERT
INTO
    tasks
(hours, startdatetime, enddatetime, description)
VALUES
(0.03, '2020-02-02 00:00:00', '2020-02-02 00:00:00', 'demo');
```

But after trying to set the global timezone in mysql as follows

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

When performing the insertion query again, the saved date is different, instead of getting `2020-02-02 00:00:00` in the columns startdatetime and enddatetime I am getting `2020-01-31 23:00:00`

The output of `SELECT @@global.time_zone;` in my local is `+00:00`

Both columns `startdatetime` and `enddatetime` are datetime type

Thanks for your help

Comment: Alter data type for a field from TIMESTAMP to DATETIME, and you'll forget about timezone problems. *when executing the following query, I hope that the values in the startdatetime and enddatetime columns are both equal to 2020-02-02 00:00:00 but in the table the value is 2020-02-01 23:00:00* But when you retrieve this value from a table using the same client with the same settings you get 2020-02-02 00:00:00, is it?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just confirmed and both columns are datetime type

Comment: DATETIME cannot be affected by timezone! [The DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) *MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (**This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME**).* Check your client for unnesessary timezone applyings.